# IBM Websphere Integration Developer - Using JAX-RS

Tags: rest, websphere

I know this isn't the best place to put this question but here it goes...

I'm using IBM Websphere Integration Developer...

I used JAX-WS runtime to create webservices from a Java test class, that instantiates severall other classes.

I did this by:

1. Right clicking on the Java test
   class
2. Web Services -> Create Web Service 
   Service: Webshpere Process Manager v7.0 Web Service Runtime: IBM
   Websphere JAX-WS
3. Checking "Publish the Web Service" -> Next -> Document Wrapped
4. Checking "Generate WSDL file into the project"
5. Checking "Configure WSDL service name" -> Finish

This resulted on the creating of a Delegate Java class on the same package of the test class
The creation of a WSDL file and an XSD file.

The Web Service is working great an this is solved...

No I need to have a similar process to generate a REST web service, and found out the JAX-RS API.

In order to have this I installed the "Websphere Application Server Feature Pack for Web 2.0" and thought that by doing this I would have the abilitty to use no only JAX-WS, JAX-RPC, but also JAX-RS, but this doesn't work.

I need the ability to generate REST Web Services automatically from a Java text class so is or isnt this possible?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the automatization supplied by the usage of JAX-WS and JAX-RPC is not possible at this moment for JAX-RS API.

Despite of this, you can do this quite easily using Rational Application Developer, but not as easily on Websphere Integration Develloper.

Regards

Comment: Had to figure that out the hard way myself.